# Facebook API - Access to Public Photos

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I have looked at a lot of posts, but I can not seem to find one that helps me with my problems. So what I need is to access the Facebook API and connect myself. This has worked well with the Javascript SDK. But now, I need to access the public photos that can be posted on Facebook. That is where I have some difficulties. I have tried to do a Topic Search, but I am not sure if this is the right tool to use and also I have looked at the Public Feed API, but this is only with an approval of Facebook.

It would be really cool if any of you knew how to access this and could help me with it :)

Comment: there is no public photo search. and you can only access public photos of a user if you authorize that user with the user_photos permission.

Comment: Ok. So if I understand this correctly, If I access the API of Facebook with my account, I can only see Pictures of me and my Friends. But not the public photos that are posted over Facebook? Cause if I do a search on Facebook about a topic I am able to see the Topic, Latest, People, Photos, Videos, Shop, Pages, Places .. and under photos, there are some public ones. So I am not sure if I do a Topic Search, if I would be able to find the public picutres of a certain topic. Does this make any sense?

Comment: exactly. with the api, you can´t just access public photos. you can´t access any user photos without authorizing that specific user.

Comment: That whole search functionality you get via the UI is not available via API. Graph API has only [very limited searching capabilities](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your help. Saved us a lot of looking!